# Porting code from CryptoAPI to CNG

Tags: cryptoapi, cng

I started writing code in CryptoAPI in unmananaged C++ to:

1. Create private keys
2. Create self signed certificate (CA)
3. Create CSRs
4. Process CSRs and sign with private CA to make certificates
   So most of the PKI...CryptoAPI is being depreciated so now I now port it all to CNG before the ship sinks. This provides mostly reference information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204779(v=vs.85).aspx

But what are the major architectural differences and gotchas? From what I can tell they splitted out some of the provider/agorithm stuff and changed function names to make it work better with FIPS but that's all that stood out. What do I need to look out for? There are hardly any CNG code samples.